# Create matrix type from two discriminated unions

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have two discriminated unions in TypeScript:

```
type Person = "alice" | "bob"
type Number = 1 | 2
```

From these two discriminated unions, how can I create a new discriminated union from every possible combination:

```
type Desired = "alice-1" | "bob-1" | "alice-2" | "bob-2"
```

Ideally `Desired` is not hardcoded as `Person` and `Number` could get quite large. If needed, `Number` could be the string union `"1" | "2"`.

Comment: [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) indeed can help you achieve what you ask, just ensure that your `tsc` is at the right version.  In the playground, if I change the version to `4.0.5`, then `template literal types` errors out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just apply template literal types and you'll get the the desired type:

```
type Person = "alice" | "bob"
type Number = 1 | 2

type Desired = `${Person}-${Number}`
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4FgBQMCeZhwArBQDOEAdnALxwBEAhgDYCWAxsNXAD40BGE316LDjgA5AK4BbboUpwAjJzgAmdIOy4AIsCKMowACayABgBIEBYmSQBaM+KmEkRoA)

This feature is available in Typescript since 4.1 with the addition of [Template literal types and mapped type 'as' clauses](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)

Comment: Nice!! May be you should also include a tip for the `tsc` version to be used for `template literal types` syntax.

Comment: @NalinRanjan Added link.